# sorting in codeigniter not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

I am facing some problem in codeigniter for sorting data.
Here's my link in the view for sorting:

```
<a href="<?= current_url() . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>&sort=asc&sort_field=name"> ASC</a>
```

But the problem is every time I hit the link, `&sort=asc&sort_field=name"` keeps on appending to the current url because of the the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` part.

But I also need `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to retain any search parameters otherwise codeigniter is not including them. Any ideas??

Comment: you should pass this as part of your data from the controller

Comment: Any idea how I can do that??

Comment: you can pass as data or simply use $this->input->get('sort'); and for sort_field in your view file

Comment: please share where r u using this query string?? MODEL or CONTROLLER?

Comment: That's what I am doing. `&sort=asc&sort_field=name` this one. But the problem is every time i click the link `&sort=asc&sort_field=name` appends to the url. For example first time the url  like http://example.com/search?&sort=asc&sort_field=name second time i click the link the url becomes http://example.com/search?&sort=asc&sort_field=name&sort=asc&sort_field=name and so on.

Comment: I am getting the query string using `$this->input->get()` in the controller then passing the values into the model

Comment: using jQuery for append url?

Comment: No. this is what I am doing `<a href="<?= current_url() . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>&sort=asc&sort_field=name"> ASC</a>`

Comment: If i remove `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` it works fine, but without that i am not getting any search parameters from the url

Comment: public function sent($sort)
{
    $data['sort'] = $sort;
    $this->view('show',$data);
}